# How to Calculate Bytes Scanned in a Spark Query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-iceberg

I'm looking for a simple measure of how much data was actually read in through the execution of a query in spark. At the most basic level - how many bytes have to be sifted through at a file level. Even better, if push down predicates limit data actually read from storage, I'd like to know by how much.

Spark plans, `explain` plans, `queryExecution` contexts hold some information, but I can't see where to get an actual measure of the data touched for a query.

Simple example -

```
spark.sql("SELECT a,b,c FROM table WHERE c = 'foo'").explain()
|== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [a#118, b#10L, c#119]
+- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(c#119) AND (c#119 = foo))
   +- BatchScan[a#10L, b#118, c#119] table [filters=c IS NOT NULL, c = 'foo']
```

End result - I'd like to measure the efficacy of my storage and table partitioning strategies from a pure data throughput standpoint.

Bonus points if you can point me to something that works with, or is specific to Iceberg tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the parameter `.explain(mode="cost")` will show statistics of the size of the data being read (if exists).